# How to combine checked and after css selector on radio and checkbox input?

Tags: css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

Is it possible to have selectors like this in CSS?

```
input[type="radio"]:checked::before {
    background-color: red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have selectors like this in CSS?

Pseudo-elements can only be on elements that have opening and closing tags. The `input` element does not have such tags, therefore, there cannot be a pseudo-element